# Is there a way to find a list of system created schemas in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Question as above. Is there a query I can run to find the schemas that are for system use? Or is my terminology wrong and I should be looking for something else in the documentation to find a list of schemas that are created by the system by default?

Comment: u looking for `SELECT schema_name  FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_owner = 'postgres';` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find it in one spot in the documentation, but here is a complete list:

| schema name | description |
| --- | --- |
| `information_schema` | Metadata views as described by the SQL standard |
| `pg_catalog` | System tables, views and functions (the catalog) |
| `pg_toast` | Schema for overflow tables for large columns |
| `pg_temp_*` | Schemas for temporary tables |
| `pg_toast_temp_*` | Schemas for overflow tables for temporary tables |

The `*` stands for a number: temporary tables for different sessions get different numbers. Note that all temporary objects can be referenced via the schema name `pg_temp`, so you could count that as a system schema as well.